# MySQL Query in bad way

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

I have below query to check customer subscription. This is not quite right way to do in query but I do not know how to optimize or correct it. Here it is.

```
SELECT sub_id FROM subscription 
WHERE start_date = CURDATE()
AND end_date > CURDATE()
AND sub_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sub_id FROM subscription
WHERE start_date < CURDATE());
```

The reason of sub query is to sieve out sub_id previously did at least a subscription.

Comment: I have almost zero experience in MySQL but your syntax looks like you are doing essentially the same WHERE clause twice. In your main you already eliminate any records with start_date <> CURDATE(); why do you have a sub query which - essentially - eliminates any records already eliminated in your main query?

Comment: looking for new customer. "WHERE start_date < CURDATE());" is old customer.

Comment: i think you have duplicate condition, `where start_date = CURDATE()` already get the sub_id which started in CURDATE(), and you don't need a subquery `AND sub_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sub_id FROM subscription WHERE start_date < CURDATE());` to filter out record which is old customer

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think we understand what you are trying to do but your sub-query is redundant. You reference the same table in both queries (subscription) and you filter on the same column (start_date) in both queries. So, in essence your effective WHERE clause becomes WHERE start_date = CURDATE() AND start_date NOT < CURDATE(). HTH.

Comment: "start_date NOT < CURDATE()" is not correct syntax in MySQL query. what is the correct syntax to write it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `SELECT DISTINCT sub_id FROM subscription WHERE start_date < CURDATE()` subquery - you already have condition `start_date = CURDATE()`.

```
SELECT sub_id FROM subscription 
WHERE start_date = CURDATE()
    AND end_date > CURDATE()
```

This query will select all subscriptions that start on `CURDATE()` and stop some other day in the future.